# Is digital preservation on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The [digital preservation Stack Exchange failed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39787/digital-preservation).  Its topic was:

> Q&A site for professionals working to ensure long term access to digital objects.

Is a digital object "data"?  Is, therefore, digital preservation on-topic?

Answer (score 5):

There may be a bit of a *coincidental* interest in this subject for the folks who frequent here, but I don't see that "digital preservation" is within the field or specific expertise of *this* site.

If you look at the example questions for the original Digital Preservation proposal (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39787?phase=definition), most of the questions are of the format:

> What storage format will last the longest for my application?

That type of expertise and specialized area of study doesn't really seem to fit anywhere within this circle:

[image]